# Green screen transparent layer questions video editing

Tags: compositing-nodes, chromakey

I have two (newbie) questions:

1)I have made a green screen video transparent in the compositing-tool. But when I am rendering this image (without a background image) and I am trying to place this in the normal video editing tool, it is not transparent. Did I do something wrong? Can I only render a green screen video with a background image? Or are there settings to do this?

2)I have downloaded a green screen video with smoke. But this smoke is too white, it would like to have the opacity 50% or something. Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: White or gray smoke works best with a black background and luma only compositing, not with green. Find a better source from someone who knows how to do it well. And yes, it is possible to composite it a the opacity you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting with ffmpeg, using RGBA(A for alpha), Container: Quicktime and Codec: PNG.

[image]

Comment: thank you, I will try that today :)

Comment: Unfortunatelly I do not have these options. I am probably using an older version of blender..

Comment: You'll have to select ffmpeg instead of PNG first and then the options will become available.

Answer (score 0):

Many Options:

- Do the compositing of the keyed video with the background elements directly on blender, and export the composited piece in whatever format the original video was using, and use it directly in your video editing app.
- Export the matte/keying information only as grayscale, and leave the original video untouched (keep in mind that every time you re-encode you are loosing quality and introducing new artifacts)

  [image]

  Then use the matte in whatever other editing/compositing app you want.
- (Best quality option) Export the Video Images and Alpha channel not as video, but as an sequence in OpenEXR format.